# How I can update code from discord.js v12 to v13? - Welcome messages with embeds

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

Recently, I received quick and efficient help with welcome messages. Now I would like to make embed welcome messages but I don't know how I can upadate my code. Code that I have is from Discord.js 12 and I would like to use discord.js v13. I made a few changes to the code to make it work on discord.js 13 but still something is wrong.

Here's index.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES" , "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS" , "DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS" , "GUILD_MEMBERS" ] , partials: ["MESSAGE" , "CHANNEL" , "REACTION"]  });


const { token } = require('./config.json')
const welcome = require('./commands/Main-Commands/Mod/welcome');


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready.')
    
    setInterval(() => {
        const statuses = [
            `Tech Tip Cyber Videos`,
            `YouTube Tutorial`,
        ]

        const status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)]
        client.user.setActivity(status, { type: "WATCHING"}) // Can Be WATCHING, STREAMING, LISTENING
    }, 2000) // Second You Want to Change Status, This Cahnges Every 2 Seconds

    welcome(client)
    
    
})



client.login(token)
```

Here's welcome.js

```
const { MessageEmbed, MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js")
const Canvas = require('canvas')
const { join } = require("path")
const user = require('discord.js')
module.exports = (client) => {
    client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
        // console.log(member) // If You Want The User Info in Console Who Joined Server Then You Can Add This Line. // Optional

        const welcome = '938780971568889876' // Welcome Channel
        const rules = '938781016502456380' // Rules Channel

        if(!member.guild) return

        const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(1770, 635) // Create Canvas Of Your Wish
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d') // 2d Only For Now
        const background = await Canvas.loadImage(join(__dirname, '../../../Images', 'welcome.png')) // BackGround Image
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0 ,0, canvas.width, canvas.height) // Setting BackGround Image
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF' // Keep Color As Nothing

        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        var name = `${member.user.username}` // UserName Of User Who Joined
        if(name.length >= 16) { // If Name Is To Long(More Then 16)
            ctx.font = 'bold 100px Sans' // Defining Size, Font
            ctx.fillStyle = '#0FEEF3' // Keep Color Of UserName
            ctx.fillText(name, 680, canvas.height / 2 - 1) // 720 Is Width From Left To Right
        } else { // If UserName Is Smaller Then 16 Then...
            ctx.font = 'bold 130px Sans' // Defining Size, Font
            ctx.fillStyle = '#0FEEF3' // Keep Color Of UserName
            ctx.fillText(name, 680, canvas.height / 2 - 1) // 720 Is Width From Left To Right // You Can Change According To Your Will
        }

        var discrim = `#${member.user.discriminator}` // Discriminator Of User
        ctx.font = 'bold 60px Sans'  // Defining Size, Font
        ctx.fillStyle = '#FA9448' // Keep Color Of Discriminator
        ctx.fillText(discrim, 680, canvas.height / 2 + 70) // You Can Change According To Your Will

        var server = `Welcome To ${member.guild.name}` 
        ctx.font = 'bold 80px Sans'  // Defining Size, Font
        ctx.fillStyle = '#21FBA1' // Keep Color Of Discriminator
        ctx.fillText(server, 670, canvas.height / 2 - 150) // You Can Change According To Your Will

        var count = `Member #${member.guild.memberCount}th`
        ctx.font = 'bold 60px Sans'  // Defining Size, Font
        ctx.fillStyle = '#21FBA1' // Keep Color Of Discriminator
        ctx.fillText(count, 680, canvas.height / 2 + 160) // You Can Change According To Your Will

        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(315, canvas.height / 2, 250, 0, Math.PI * 2, true) // Avatar Of User
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.clip() // Make Avatar As Circle, By Default Its Square

        const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' })) // Get Users Avatar
        ctx.drawImage(avatar, 65, canvas.height / 2- 250, 500 , 500) // Adjusting Avatar In Circle Of Image

        const attachment = new MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome.png') // Send As Attachment

        const embed = new MessageEmbed() // Send As Embed
        .setAuthor(`${user.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setDescription(`
Welcome To **${member.guild.name}** <@${member.id}>
Please Check <#${rules}>
        `)
        .setImage('attachment://welcome.png')
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .attachFiles(attachment) // Send Welcome Image
        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcome) // Get Welcome Channel
        channel.send(embed) // Send Embed
       
       
        client.on("message", message => {
            const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
            const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
        
        
        })
    })

}
```

Here's config.json

```
{
    "token": "Your Token",
    "def_prefix": "+"
}
```

If someone is able to help me, please explain what is wrong with my code and what should I change to make it work.

Here's the error I receive when new user join server:

```
.setAuthor(`${user.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())        
                                  ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error said, `message` is not defined in this scope. You should use `member.user.displayAvatarURL()`.

Comment: Okay. This is solved. But now I have another error. Can you help me with that please? Error message:  node:12988) DeprecationWarning: Passing strings for MessageEmbed#setAuthor is deprecated. Pass a sole object instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

Comment: Instead of two arguments, use one with an object: `{ name: "name", iconURL: "iconURL" }` for example

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming in the line where you are using `setAuthor` in your embed. At that point, there is nothing defined as message since the `messageCreate` event listener was defined after that, so it would be better to change the `setAuthor()` in your embed to `member.user.displayAvatarURL()`. You are also requiring `discord.js` and putting it in the `user` variable instead of getting the user details of the person who joined, so you need to correct that to `member.user.tag`. You also need to change the way you are declaring the author in the embed. In `discord.js` v13, you need to pass an object instead of two strings, so you have to change that line to:

```js
.setAuthor({ name: member.user.tag, iconURL: member.user.displayAvatarURL()})
```

Comment: Ok so my code looks like this now: https://pastebin.com/jLU7xf4Z And I receive error. Can you help me with that please? Here's error code:                                         
`TypeError: (intermediate value).setAuthor(...).setDescription(...).setImage(...).setColor(...).attachFiles is not a function`

Comment: Yeah, for that just remove the `.attachFiles()` line in your embed and then when you are sending the embed, change it to `channel.send({ embeds: [embed], files: [attachment]})

Comment: Thank you. But I have another error :( Here's how the code actually looks: https://pastebin.com/FtN1WGAs I had to add `const prefix = '+'
` because I had `prefix is not defined` error. Now after new user join server something like this appears `(node:15216) DeprecationWarning: Passing strings for MessageEmbed#setAuthor is deprecated. Pass a sole object instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:15216) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead
` Can you help me with that please?

Comment: In your code, change `client.on('message')` to `client.on('messageCreate')`

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Change your `setAuthor` in your embed to `.setAuthor({ name: `${user.tag}`, iconURL: member.user.displayAvatarURL()})`

Comment: Ok. So I changed that and now we have "problems in file" https://imgur.com/a/Gmed5gR If I delete curly bracket right here  `${user.tag}` Then these problems go away, but the code won't work. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean? What is the error you get when you run the code?

Comment: `.setAuthor({ name: ${user.tag}, iconURL: member.user.displayAvatarURL()})
                            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'`

Comment: You have to put it in backticks so change it to .setAuthor({ name: \`${user.tag}\`, iconURL: member.user.displayAvatarURL()})

Comment: Ok. It works now, but bot doesn't show username, just its id. Can you help me with that? Here's how it look: https://imgur.com/a/LBH5GCN                                                                   And here most recently code: https://pastebin.com/cw0sCUXm

Comment: Change the `.setAuthor()` to `.setAuthor(\`${member.user.tag}\`). It should work now